# Typescript Property '' does not exist on type 'never'. in React NodeJs stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am *slowly* teaching myself NodeJs, Express, React, monogoDB and Typescript.. (coming from a MVC C# SQL DB Background)

My very simple Hello world program just needs to communicate with the Express server to display a list of Users. My Express server is on Port 3001 and my Create-React-App Front end is on Port 3000.

my App Component is as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const logo = require('./logo.svg');

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {users: []}
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Fetching Users");
    fetch('/users')
      .then(res=> res.json())
      .then(users=> this.setState({users}));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React test</h2>
          {this.state.users.map(user => 
            <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The error:

> (21,28): error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.

I can see the problem is that I havent defined users to include properties users.id and users.username.. But I am unsure how to do this?

Comment: *”Javascript wouldnt have an issue here....”* - then, if you don’t want typing, *use JavaScript*. If you actually want to use TS, see http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I would like typing.. And would like to learn new ways. I just don't know how it works in this situation. do I need to create an interface? (I did try this) but obviously got the syntax wrong. I'll remove that line.. It wasn't meaning "old way is better"

Comment: You need to tell the compiler what `state.users` is supposed to be an array *of*. You don’t necessarily need to create an interface, but that does allow you to give a useful name to the shape you’re describing.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me to fish (as opposed to giving me a fish) :)    I posted my answer, I think users: Array<any>() may also work.. but i did create an interface in this situation

Answer (score 6):

I may have posted this question a bit to quickly.
but I solved my answer

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const logo = require('./logo.svg');

interface Iuser {
  id: number,
  username: string
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {users: Array<Iuser>()}
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("Fetching Users");
    fetch('/users')
      .then(res=> res.json())
      .then(users=> this.setState({users}));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React test</h2>
          {this.state.users.map(user => 
            <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

(Creating an interface for the array object)

I did try this previously but had the syntax wrong.